# Disable Chrome 'Multiple Automatic Download' Prompt with Ruby Watir ChromeDriver-DesiredCapabilites

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver

So we have a bunch of automated scripts that will go to a specific website and download a set of files but Chrome seems to have a 'Multiple Automatic Download' prompt that needs to be disabled for the script to run by itself and to let it download multiple files.

I found a solution but I am having trouble implementing it. The solution has:

```
@caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilites.chrome("chromeOptions"=>{"args"=>["--test-type"]})
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile, :desired_capabilities => @caps
```

Error I am getting:

```
Started ChromeDriver
version=20.0.1133.0
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.18.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:
64:in `create_capabilities': unknown option: {:desired_capabilities=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::
Capabilities:0x5626368 @capabilities={:native_events=>false, :browser_name=>"chrome", :rotatable=>fa
lse, "chromeOptions"=>{"args"=>["--test-type"]}, :firefox_profile=>nil, :javascript_enabled=>true, :
proxy=>nil, :css_selectors_enabled=>true, :platform=>:any, :takes_screenshot=>false, :version=>""}>}
 (ArgumentError)
```

I've been trying to code this in multiple ways but can't seem to get the formatting down, asking for help to piece these together please!
I am unable to do any updates to anything atm.
Chrome v.19.0.1084.56
Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Its not duplicate, that answer did not work for me. I tried that originally. Please open this question up to be answered please.

Comment: Just reconfirmed that the solution you are redirecting to does not work. Please open the ticket.

Comment: Thanks for making my question on this site another complete waste of time [@Justin Ko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1200545/justin-ko)! I really appreciate the minimum effort with an unrelated solution and closing it!

Comment: Sorry, I am missing the difference in the question. Both questions seem to be asking how to disable the multiple automatic downloads prompt. Can you please clarify how this question is different?